# How to use size of file inside Ant target

Tags: java, ant, filesize

I'm currently in the process of replacing my homebrewn build script by an Ant build script.

Now I need to replace various tokens by the size of a specific file. I know how to get the size in bytes via the `<length>` task and store in in a property, but I need the size in kilobytes and megabytes too.

How can I access the file size in other representations (KB, MB) or compute these values from within the Ant target and store them in a property?

**Edit:** After I discovered the `<script>` task, it was fairly easy to calculate the other values using some JavaScript and add a new property to the project using `project.setNewProperty("foo", "bar");`.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post the script you wrote as an answer.

Comment: Actually a good idea. I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution that does not require any third-party library or custom tasks using the [`<script>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) that allows for using JavaScript (or any other [Apache BSF](http://jakarta.apache.org/bsf) or [JSR 223](https://scripting.dev.java.net/) supported language) from within an Ant target.

```
<target name="insert-filesize">
    <length file="${afile}" property="fs.length.bytes" />

    <script language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        var length_bytes = project.getProperty("fs.length.bytes");
        var length_kbytes = Math.round((length_bytes / 1024) * Math.pow(10,2))
                          / Math.pow(10,2);
        var length_mbytes = Math.round((length_kbytes / 1024) * Math.pow(10,2))
                          / Math.pow(10,2);
        project.setNewProperty("fs.length.kb", length_kbytes);
        project.setNewProperty("fs.length.mb", length_mbytes);
    ]]>
    </script>

    <copy todir="${target.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${source.dir}">
            <include name="**/*" />
            <exclude name="**/*.zip" />
        </fileset>
        <filterset begintoken="$$$$" endtoken="$$$$">
            <filter token="SIZEBYTES" value="${fs.length.bytes}"/>
            <filter token="SIZEKILOBYTES" value="${fs.length.kb}"/>
            <filter token="SIZEMEGABYTES" value="${fs.length.mb}"/>
        </filterset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: What alternatives do we have when JavaScript it's removed? https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335

Answer (score 3):

There is a math task at http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/ that may be useful

Comment: Thanks, but I've found a solution that does not require additional libraries.

Comment: script is certainly better way to do it, didn't know Ant supported beanshell already. Thanks for the info.